# Laravel 4 save dates on database

Tags: php, date, laravel-4, save, eloquent

I want to save dates using laravel 4, I have been looking on the internet but the only good solution that I found was using

```
$start_at = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_at));
```

but I am sure that this is kind of archaic code used by Isaac Newton xd, plus if I want to retrieve it, I need to used again.
In the manual, I found the "variable protected $dates = array('My_date', 'Another_date');" or using the "public function getDates ()", http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators I even change the file Model.php, but I have this error all the time "Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing"

```
class Insurance extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'insurance';
    protected $dates = array('start_at', 'end_at');
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_insurance';
    protected $fillable = array (
            'id_vehicle',
            'start_at',
            'end_at' 
    );

    public function getDates()
    {
        return array('start_at', 'end_at');
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP has a great [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class. Just put `$start_at` into the constructor (if it gets parsed correctly by strtotime) and format it how you like later.

Comment: Do you want to save a specific date or do you want to get a date? Getting a date works out of the box, if you add the field to getDates Eloquent makes a DATETIME / TIMESTAMP field into a Carbon object (which is an extension of the DateTime class).

Comment: I want to save it in the database, what I want is set a columns date

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Carbon library for PHP.

Set your column type in the database as date. (mySql allows that).

If your form has inputs which give separate parts of the Date such as year, month and Date, you could create the input to be inserted as

```
Carbon::createFromDate(      
 $dateOfBirth['year'],      
 $dateOfBirth['month'],
 $dateOfBirth['date'])->toDateString();
```

This can be inserted into your eloquent Model.